# Как запустить программу и передать логин и пароль для аутентификации (CheckPoint Endpoint Security)

Tags: c#, cmd, безопасность, vpn

есть программа checkpoint endpoint Security, которую я хочу запускать через c# в качестве процесса, но при запуске нужно вводить логин и пароль, хотелось бы узнать есть ли способ, запустить ее и сразу через код передать логин и пароль, чтобы она открылась и сама авторизовалась. Может через cmd как то можно открывать программу и передавать в качестве аргументов логин и пароль, чтобы сразу проходить этап аутентификации в программе?

Comment: Не понятно о какой части программы идет речь: администрирование, клиентская часть, иное? Может лучше в поддержку пользователей написать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать клиент CheckPoint SNX (SSL Network Extender). На линксe это консольная утилита, в Windows системах возможно тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Описание работы через командную строку тут:
"c:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Connect\CLI_help.txt"

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/840582)